# CakePHP routing regex matching when I don't want it to

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This code in my routes.php is built to route URLs from an old version of a site, to a function that then redirects to the new URL.  It's working good for the URLs it is supposed to work for, such as `/p2045/some-product`, but it's also matching URLs that begin with a p, such as `/products`.  I assumed that the regex below would not match this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Router::connect('/p:id/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'products',
        'action' => 'legacy_redirect',
        'id' => '^[0-9]+$'
    )
);
```

Comment: Where does this route send `/products` when it matches that?

Comment: To the legacy_redirect action of the products controller. $this->params['id'] is equal to "roducts" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action I think you should use something like:

```
Router::connect(
    '/p:id/*',
    array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'legacy_redirect'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

Comment: Took me ages to see that my regex bit was in the same array as everything else - thanks.